# When I try pack pycrypto using pyinstaller error has occurred

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pycrypto

I use last version pyinstaller, python 2.7.5, OSX

And when I try pack this code:

```
import  Crypto.Cipher._AES as AES
import Crypto.Hash._SHA256 as SHA256 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = AES.new('1234567890123456')
    cipher = c.encrypt('blabblabblabblab')
    print(cipher.encode('hex'))

    h = SHA256.new('blabblabblabblab')
    print(h.hexdigest())
```

> python pyinstaller.py /Users/alexey/secure_backup/cryptotest.py -F

It successful, but this output has occurs when I run program from console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/alexey/Downloads/pyinstaller-develop/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 382, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/nd/1m2t9wmx4jv1gdw_h0s9sp3w0000gp/T/_MEI81X1du/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.so, 2): image not found
```

--hidden-import=Crypto.Cipher._AES also not work

Comment: Same bug of wx,etc. check my blog http://sadopy.blogspot.com.tr/2015/09/py-installer-wxpython-error-corecore-etc.html

Comment: @dsgdfg, could you translate your blog here?